# Почему атрибут ведёт себя как функция

Tags: python

Натолкнулся на следующего формата код:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Duck = namedtuple('Duck', 'bill tail')
>>> duck = Duck('wide orange', 'long')
>>> duck
Duck(bill='wide orange', tail='long')
```

Мы присвоили результат работы функции namedtuple атрибуту Duck, который затем непонятным для меня образом стал вызываться как функция, в которую к тому же ещё передали аргументы. Второй вопрос связан с первым параметром функции namedtuple. Говорится, что туда передаётся имя, но где оно конкретно отражается, ведь мы уже имеем атрибут с данным названием. Буду благодарен за обьяснения.

Comment: Ответ на первый вопрос: вызывается метод `__call__`, почитайте про него.

Answer (score 6):

`namedtuple()` возвращает новый подкласс кортежа с именованными полями. Здесь `Duck` - имя типа.

Теперь, когда вы вызываете `namedtuple('Duck', 'bill tail')`, создается именованный кортеж. Класс с именем `Duck` создается внутри.

Если к вызову добавить параметр `verbose=True` вы сможете все это увидеть:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Duck = namedtuple('Duck', 'bill tail', verbose=True)
```

выведет:

```
from builtins import property as _property, tuple as _tuple
from operator import itemgetter as _itemgetter
from collections import OrderedDict

class Duck(tuple):
    'Duck(bill, tail)'

    __slots__ = ()

    _fields = ('bill', 'tail')

    def __new__(_cls, bill, tail):
        'Create new instance of Duck(bill, tail)'
        return _tuple.__new__(_cls, (bill, tail))

    ...
```

Теперь, когда вы пишите `duck = Duck('wide orange', 'long')` вызывается конструктор класса `Duck` и для этого и нужно это имя.

Если вы посмотрите тип созданного объекта `type(duck)`, то увидите:

```
>>>__main__.Duck
```

**UPD**

Пишут, что начиная с 3.7, параметр `verbose` и атрибут `_source удалили`.

Comment: Добавлю, что начиная с 3.7, параметр `verbose` и атрибут `_source` удалили.

Answer (score 4):

Функция в качестве своего результата может возвращать всё что угодно. Например, другую функцию или класс (а классы так же как и функции можно вызвать).

В данном случае `namedtuple` возвращает как-раз таки класс. Поэтому результат вызова функции `namedtuple` можно вызвать.

Имя нужно передать вот для чего: когда `namedtuple` создаёт класс, она не может знать, что после создания результат её работы будет присвоен переменной Duck. Но при создании ей уже нужно знать, с каким именем создавать класс. Поэтому приходится передавать имя в качестве аргумента.

Answer (score 3):

`Duck` - не атрибут, а переменная. Переменные хранят значения. Значениями в Python являются в том числе вызываемые объекты, например классы или функции. В данном случае функция `namedtuple` вернула класс, который был записан в переменную `Duck`. Имя, переданное в функцию `namedtuple` выступает именем класса, которое, в частности выводится при переводе объекта этого класса в строку (например, при выводе через `print`). В общем случае, имя переданное в `namedtuple` может не совпадать с именем переменной, в которую вы записали сформированный класс.